# Inserting an Image in google cloud storage using php api

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to setup storage in google cloud platform. Honestly now i am kind of confused on what to do.

I am using the following code.

```
require_once("vendor/autoload.php");

use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageObject;

use Google\Cloud\Storage;

$projectId = 'YOUR_PROJECT_ID';

$storage = new StorageClient([
     'projectId' => 'xx',
    'key'=> 'yy'
]);

$file_name = "imagename";

$obj = new StorageObject();

$obj->setName($file_name);


  $storage->objects->insert(
        "kmapsimage",
        $obj,
        ['name' => $file_name, 'data' => file_get_contents("https://kmapst.blob.core.windows.net/images/kmap581b939a7a28c.jpeg"),'mimeType' => 'image/jpeg']
);
```

On executing the function i get the following error.

```
Argument 1 passed to Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageObject::__construct() must implement interface Google\Cloud\Storage\Connection\ConnectionInterface, none given, called in /var/www/html/test_imageupload.php on line 35 and defined in /var/www/html/vendor/google/cloud/src/Storage/StorageObject.php on line 71
```

I just want to upload images to google storage.

Answer (score 3):

Be sure that you use your credentials that you can download from GCP in json format.

In the header I have this:

```
putenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=".$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/uploads/my-fe1tyui28f4f.json");

require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/php-docs-samples/storage/api/vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

$storage = new StorageClient();

// Primera imagen......
$file = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/uploads/".$filename."_200.jpg", 'r');
$bucket = $storage->bucket("my_bucket");
$object = $bucket->upload($file, ['name' => $dir."/".$filename."_200.jpg"]);
$object = $bucket->object($dir."/".$filename."_200.jpg");
$object->update(['acl' => []], ['predefinedAcl' => 'PUBLICREAD']);
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

The docs show a [simpler](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/v0.20.0/storage/bucket?method=upload) way

Given your relevant code:

```
$storage = new StorageClient([
    'projectId' => 'xx',
    'key'=> 'yy'
]);
```

> // Using the upload method seems a bit more straightforward

```
$bucket = $storage->bucket('bucket-name');
$file = fopen('path/to/file', 'r');
$object = $bucket->upload($file, ['name' => 'fileName']);
```